# How to create a map where the color is based on one variable (discrete), but the gradient is based on another variable (continuous)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to recreate the pop vs soda map.  I am using the `state` from `maps` library.  Here is the code I am using.

```
states = map_data("state")

states%>%
  full_join(soft_drinks_plot, by = c("region" = "State"))%>%
  ggplot()+
  geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, 
fill = max_choice, color = max_choice), color = "white")+
  scale_fill_gradient2(aesthetics = "color")
```

My `soft_drinks_plot` data frame looks something like this:

```
State            Pop  Soda  Coke Other Total max_choice per_max
alabama          153   582  2849   665  4249 Coke         0.671
alaska           324   636    60    92  1112 Soda         0.572
arizona          586  2799   437   174  3996 Soda         0.700
arkansas         154   347  1442    80  2023 Coke         0.713
california       925 20119  2892  1941 25877 Soda         0.777
```

Here is code to recreate it:

```
soft_drinks_plot <- read.table(text =
"State            Pop  Soda  Coke Other Total max_choice per_max
alabama          153   582  2849   665  4249 Coke         0.671
alaska           324   636    60    92  1112 Soda         0.572
arizona          586  2799   437   174  3996 Soda         0.700
arkansas         154   347  1442    80  2023 Coke         0.713
california       925 20119  2892  1941 25877 Soda         0.777",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I want the color to be the `max_choice` and I want the gradient to be shaded using the `per_max`.  Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

So I can fade the map using `alpha = per_max` inside of the aesthetics.

```
states%>%
  full_join(soft_drinks_plot, by = c("region" = "State"))%>%
  ggplot()+
  geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, 
fill = max_choice, alpha = per_max), color = "black")
```

Is there any way to make it more of a radial shade?